# Хочу сделать топ статей за неделю, но они не выводятся по какой-то причине

Tags: html, python, django

Статьи должны фильтроваться по количеству лайков на них и высвечивать топ статей за неделю. Я написал небольшую функцию, которая должна сортировать по лайкам, но она это почему-то не делает. Еще хочу сделать чтобы фильтровалось в первую неделю

views.py

```
def Toplikes(request):
    context =[Articles.objects.annotate(views_count=Count('views')).order_by('views_count')]
    return render(request, 'news/posts.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    tags = TaggableManager()
    article_like = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    article_dislike = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    views = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

posts.html

```
    {% for article in object_list %}
    <h2>{{ article.title}}</h2>
    <span id="count{{ article.pk }}">{{ object.article_like }}</span>
    <input type="button" class="like" id="{{ article.pk }}" value="Like" />
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('<int:pk>/article', views.Toplikes, name='Like'),

]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Вы в контекст шаблона передаёте множество вместо словаря.

Comment: Все я вродибы все исправил и шаблон изменил он просмотры выводил а теперь статьи . И теперь выводит статьи только не самые популярные а просто статьи

Answer (score 0):

1. Как сказал [Сергей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev)

В контексте передается массив, а не словарь

```
context = dict(object_list=Articles.objects.annotate(views_count=Count('views')).order_by('views_count'))
```

2 - У вас поле "просмотры" - число. Зачем тогда вы считаете их кол-во ? И сортировка у вас неверная, нужна по убыванию (от большего к меньшему), т.е. со знаком `-`

```
Articles.objects.order_by('-views')
```